# Laravel: How to avoid reading another RedirectIfAuthenticated

Tags: laravel

Laravel 8
I am seperating the frontend and admin.
app\Admin\Http\Middle\RedirectIfAuthenticated
app\Frontend\Http\Middle\RedirectIfAuthenticated
app\Models
...

Except models, other folders are either in Admin or Frontend

**app\Admin\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return redirect('aaa');
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

**app\Frontend\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
        return redirect('bbb');
    }
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

Frontend URL http://xxx/login, if I had loggedin, it should redirects to http://xxx/bbb, but it redirects to aaa.
Why frontend page still uses admin's  RedirectIfAuthenticated?

I found that in older version, it's

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
```

in laravel 8.75, it's

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
```

This is why I can't get $guard name...

Comment: Middleware are supposed to redirect if something fails the condition. For example, admin middleware redirects when you are NOT and admin. Anyway, the redirection after login is not in your middleware, it's in your auth controller.

Comment: check logibController of each one

Comment: Middleware are doing things before controller. RedirectIfAuthenticated means, if someone had logged in, and visits login page, it should redirect to some other page.

Comment: And RedirectIfAuthenticated is just an example. The problem is, when visit frontend pages, laravel still uses files inside admin, like middleware, exception.